# Make IFRAME search order inline with other content

Tags: html, iframe, webkit, webkitgtk

I have a webpage with several IFRAMEs. When searching this page using the browser the matches in the IFRAME are cycled through after all the other matches in the main page has been cycled through.

This causes the page to jump up again, and the matches are not selected in the same order as they appear on the screen.

To see how this works check e.g. [this page](http://jkorpela.fi/html/iframe.html) and search for `news`.

How do I make the content of the IFRAME be searchable in the same order as it appears on the screen?

I am developing this page only for [webkit](https://webkitgtk.org/), but I observe the same behavior with firefox.